# JAX-RS passing parameters to a PUT request

Tags: rest, http, jax-rs, http-put

I've heard that in **REST** world, `POST` is recommended to **create** an entry, while `PUT` is recommended to **update** an entry.

First, I'd like a confirmation of this statement.

Then, using this assumptions, let's say I have a @POST method to create a user and a @PUT method to update a user (with a @QueryParam to pass the user ID).

What is the correct way to pass parameters to `POST` and `PUT`?

Is `@FormParam` appropriate for `@PUT`? Or should I pass a `JSON` in the body?

Should I pass parameters the same way for both `@POST` and `@PUT` or a different way?

Or should I use `POST` for both?

Edit: This question initially showed an example that did not work for me, but it was because my testing tool was doing it wrong. It works with POSTMAN now.

Comment: Show us the request you make for `PUT`.

Comment: Actually while trying to show you the request I noticed that my tool was not using `x-www-form-url-encoded`. Once I switched to that it worked for PUT... But I'd still like to know how I SHOULD do it

Comment: I will edit my question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with REST, you typically use the following:

- The method `POST` of the element list resource to add an element
- The method `PUT` of the element resource to completely update an element
- The method `PATCH` of the element resource to partially update an element

Since what you must send corresponds to the state of the resource, you have to provide it within the request body.

The two bodies (for adding and updating) is similar but there are some differences. For example, if you expect the RESTful service to autogenerate some fields, you don't have to provide corresponding ones.

Here are sample requests:

```
POST /contacts
{
    "lastName": "my last name",
    "firstName": "my first name",
}
(corresponding response status code: 201 - Created)

PUT /contacts/contactid
{
    "lastName": "my last name",
    "firstName": "my first name",
}
(corresponding response status code: 204 - No content)
```

You can notice that JSON isn't the only format you can use. XML, YAML, and so on could also be used.

I think that the following link could give you some hints:

- **Designing a Web API** - https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/designing-a-web-api/

Hope it helps you,
Thierry